# How to Get SoundCloud RSS Download Stats via API?

Tags: api, rss, soundcloud

With SoundCloud's recent update [showing RSS Downloads as a separate statistic](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1962252-my-podcast-stats-look-different-what-changed-), I am not able to find a way to get this stat via the API.

Looking at the [HTTP API Reference for Tracks](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), I can see options for:

- comment_count
- download_count
- playback_count
- favoritings_count

Is there an option to get the RSS download count? Has the documentation just not been updated? If this isn't currently an option, will it be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the stat-reporting direction at SoundCloud has changed, and RSS plays will be part of the overall play number and broken-out in other ways.

https://www.soundcloudcommunity.com/soundcloud/topics/new-rss-stats-need-to-be-reflect-in-total-plays

Answer (score 1):

On May 8th 2015, I checked the API via the developer console on Soundcloud and did not see any way to view the RSS download count, unfortunately.